# ¿como puedo sumar los meses de la fecha actual en javascript?

Tags: javascript

buenas tengo este codigo

```
var d = new Date();
var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+4) + "-" + d.getDate();
    console.log(strDate);
```

pero como es fin de año al sumar me da 22-15-2018 cuando deberia ser 22-03-2019

como le puedo hacer para q lo traega correctamente?

Comment: @shadow si me funciono pero el mes me lo despliega 2019-3-22 asi en vez de 2019-03-22, ya que para validar si la fecha seleccionada es mayor no la reconoce si la comparo con 2019-04-22 como q no la toma en cuenta y la deja pasar

Comment: te hice una respuesta de lo que ocupas @Juan Jose chécala y me avisas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenemos a nuestra disposición el método `setMonth()` al cual le vamos a hacer el incremento de meses que queremos sumar a la fecha original o actual

`setMonth()` establece un mes específico de acuerdo al año establecido, el cual en nuestro ejercicio es 2018 al momento de hacer `var e = new Date()`

```
var e = new Date()
e.setMonth(e.getMonth() + 4)

console.log("fecha: "+e.getFullYear() +"-"+ (e.getMonth()+1) +"-"+ e.getDate())
```

El ejercicio anterior, nos mostrará como fecha final: `"fecha: 2019-4-22"` pero ¿por qué?

Pues por que los meses empiezan en la posición 0, entonces si yo dejo únicamente +4 le indico que llegue hasta marzo, por el contrario si aparte de eso, dentro de mi console.log, hago `e.getMonth() + 1` entonces ya empieza en la posición 1 que en meses sería `Febrero` por lo cual me va a mostrar la fecha en el mes de `Abril`

Es decir los meses los lee así:

```
Posición    0   |    1    |   2     |   3   |   4
---------------------------------------------------
Mes       Dic   | Enero   | Febrero | Marzo | Abril
```